# Unable to instantiate ViewModel in Android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to achieve MVVM design pattern in my application.I have created viewmodel and repository class but when I am trying to instantiate viewmodel in my MainActivity its showing error  red line below `MainActivity` at the time of instantiation in below line.

`pdfViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(MainActivity.this).get(PdfViewModel.class);`

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PdfViewModel pdfViewModel;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pdfViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(MainActivity.this).get(PdfViewModel.class);

 }
}
```

**PdfViewModel.java**

```
public class PdfViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private PdfRepository pdfRepository;

public PdfViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    pdfRepository = new PdfRepository(application);
}

public LiveData<List<Pdfs>> getAllPdfs(){
    return pdfRepository.getMutableLiveData();
}
}
```

**PdfRepository.java**

```
public class PdfRepository {

private ArrayList<Pdfs> list = new ArrayList<>();
private MutableLiveData<List<Pdfs>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private Application application;

public PdfRepository(Application application){
    this.application = application;
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Pdfs>>  getMutableLiveData(){

    SharedPreferences preferences = application.getSharedPreferences("Credentials", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = preferences.getString("email",null);

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Call<List<Pdfs>> call = apiService.getFiles(email);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pdfs>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Pdfs>> call, Response<List<Pdfs>> response) {

            if(response.body() != null){
                list = (ArrayList<Pdfs>) response.body();
                mutableLiveData.setValue(list);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Pdfs>> call, Throwable t) {

            TastyToast.makeText(application,t.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
        }
    });

    return mutableLiveData;
}

}
```

What needs to be corrected in the above code?

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Nothing just a red line is showing

Comment: Can you replace `MainActivity.this` with `this` only.

Comment: Have you compiled the code? Do you have compilation errors? If yes, please provide the errors. Aletrnatively you can click on the red line and observe a red light bulb to appear. Then click on the light bulb for possible solutions.

Comment: On changing to `this` its saying cannot resolve constructor

Comment: on compilation error is

Comment: `no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(MainActivity)
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner,Factory) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)`

Comment: @Digvijay Try this: pdfViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PdfViewModel.class); instead of the one you currently have.

Comment: Please refrain from adding shouty **THANKS** messages to your posts. References from Meta Stack Overflow about conversational material are available on request. I have helpfully downvoted in an effort to remind you about this - several of your posts have been edited for this already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to create a new instance of the class `ViewModelProvider` (with the `new` keyword) and that's not the right way to instantiate a ViewModel.

On `MainActivity`, instead of:

```
pdfViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(MainActivity.this).get(PdfViewModel.class);
```

try:

```
pdfViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PdfViewModel.class);
```

Notice the right class is `ViewModelProviders` (with an "s" at the end) and you need to call the static method `of` instead of creating a new instance of it with `new`. If you can't import that class, make sure you have the dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0' added to `app/build.gradle`.

To make your code even clearer, I'd suggest learning about the Kotlin KTX method `viewModels`, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment). You'd need to use Kotlin for that though.

Comment: `ViewModelProviders` is not showing up in suggestion instead `ViewModelProvider` is showing.

Comment: Try adding 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0' to your module build.gradle.